# PHP add target="_blank

Tags: php, target

I hope everyone doing great, I need help how I can add target blank to a specific code

this is the code:

```
if( !empty($social_fb) ){
        $result .= '<a href="'.esc_attr($social_fb).'"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>';
    }
```

I try to add this:

```
if( !empty($social_fb) ){
        $result .= '<a href=" target="_blank'.esc_attr($social_fb).'"><i class="tana-social tana-size-26 tana-facebook tana-circle fa fa-facebook"></i></a>';
    }
```

but not work!

I hope someone can help me, many thanks in advances!
Regards
Manny

Comment: you haven't closed href.close it before target.if you check html source code you can see the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
if( !empty($social_fb) ){
    $result .= '<a href="'.esc_attr($social_fb).'" target="_blank"><i class="tana-social tana-size-26 tana-facebook tana-circle fa fa-facebook"></i></a>';
}
```

Comment: lol Work like charm, thanks mate I really appreciate it!

Comment: lol no problem, check the question to resolved then :)

Answer (score 1):

You're building bad html:

```
 $result .= '<a href=" target="_blank'.esc_a
                      ^--mising href ^---missing "
```

so you're effectively buiding

```
<a href=" target="_blankfoobar ....
```

which will be parsed like this by the browser:

```
<a href="target=" _blankfoobar">etc...
```

making the text `target=` your actual href, and `_blankfoobar` being an unknown/illegal attribute.